# TFS build agent is checking out some files

Tags: tfs, build

I'm facing an issue with TFS2012 where I have a gated check setup. Sometimes (not always) users are having files checked out by the build service (not a concrete type of files) with operations like add, delete and edit.

My first clue was something with the gated check in but accordingly to the information reconciles are being done, but the problem is that so far I can't trigger the issue, it just happens "sometimes".

I noticed that the build agent is doing the check outs, since if I go to the agent working folder I can find the files that have been checked out. It seems that the agent is reverting a change made by a user, but I still didn't fully understand it.

Do you have any idea what on the TFS could be causing this behavior, at least to give me some pointers on where to look for the issue.

Comment: Sounds like you have a customized build process template that's doing it. What build process template are you using?

Comment: I see my TFS Build account having loads of checkouts in workspaces, but this is never a problem for me. Is there a specific problem the checkouts are causing?

Comment: The users are complaining of having some files blocked because of it.

I'm using a custom template, but it doesn't do any more check outs than the default template. The customization is just to trigger deployments after the build.